# Zabbix doesn't show created "MAPS"

Tags: php, linux, apache, centos, zabbix

As in topic, after upgrading Zabbix server from 4x to 5.0 suddenly maps stopped working. Apache server log shows me when I go into Maps in zabbix:

`[Sat Aug 22 11:41:31.240669 2020] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 59440] [client 172.29.0.160:59446] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Warning:  imagecreatefromstring(): Data is not in a recognized format in /usr/share/zabbix/include/images.inc.php`

What I try was:

1. Reinstall Httpd (Apache server)
2. Reinstall PHP
3. Reinstall Zabbix server

Also, I am googling by the last 3 days and can't find an answer why it happened? All libraries are installed and also Zavbbix system check show all on the green.

Some system information:
Centoes 7

[httpd + PHP 7.2.24]
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Server built:   Apr  2 2020 13:13:23

[PHP]
`rpm -qa | grep php rh-php72-php-bcmath-7.2.24-1.el7.x86_64 rh-php72-php-gd-7.2.24-1.el7.x86_64 rh-php72-php-json-7.2.24-1.el7.x86_64 rh-php72-php-pdo-7.2.24-1.el7.x86_64 rh-php72-runtime-1-2.el7.x86_64 rh-php72-php-process-7.2.24-1.el7.x86_64 rh-php72-php-zip-7.2.24-1.el7.x86_64 rh-php72-php-cli-7.2.24-1.el7.x86_64 rh-php72-php-pear-1.10.5-1.el7.noarch rh-php72-php-fpm-7.2.24-1.el7.x86_64 rh-php72-php-common-7.2.24-1.el7.x86_64 rh-php72-1-2.el7.x86_64 rh-php72-php-mbstring-7.2.24-1.el7.x86_64 rh-php72-php-ldap-7.2.24-1.el7.x86_64 rh-php72-php-xml-7.2.24-1.el7.x86_64 rh-php72-php-mysqlnd-7.2.24-1.el7.x86_64`

Some screenshots:
[Zabbix maps screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKQkR.png)
[PHPinfo (Gd)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJHhK.png)

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded Centos from 7 to 8 versions and also reinstalled zabbix packages from version 7 to desired. After than all Maps stared show correctly.